# Coding Karatsuba multiplication

Tags: python, karatsuba

my code below seem to work well if either number's length is even, but if both length of number are odd(like in the pic), it outputs the wrong result. I have no idea where it went wrong or how to fix it.

```
def karatsubaMulti(num1, num2):
    len1 = len(str(num1))
    len2 = len(str(num2))

    if len1==1 or len2==1:
        return num1*num2

    else:
        maxLen = max(len1, len2)

        if maxLen > len1:
            a=0
            b=num1
        else:
            a = num1 // pow(10, maxLen//2)
            b = num1 %  pow(10, maxLen//2)

        if maxLen > len2:
            c=0
            d=num2
        else:
            c = num2 // pow(10, maxLen//2)
            d = num2 % pow(10, maxLen//2)
        z1 = karatsubaMulti(a, c)
        z2 = karatsubaMulti(b, d)
        z3 = karatsubaMulti(a+b, c+d)
        return z1 * pow(10, maxLen) + (z3-z1-z2) * pow(10, maxLen//2) + z2
x = 171
y = 571

xy1 = karatsubaMulti(x, y)

print(xy1)
```

Comment: Please paste the code as a text in your question - not as a image. Welcome to SO.

Comment: + You can format code in stackoverflow between triple accent graves.

Comment: it's edited now thanks

Comment: Remark: implement it like this in Python is completely useless, because a *single division* by a large number (10^something large) is more expensive than a multiplication already. // By the way, you can use `**` for the power operator.

Comment: It is just a practice of recursive calls. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Look at the formula carefully, compare that with the correct formula, and you'll see that the square of `pow(10, maxLen//2)` is not `pow(10, maxLen)`.

Comment: I see what  are suggesting here. But when comes to odd length, what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @n.y You know where the bug is now, try to figure it out yourself.